# Which user is connecting to beeline?

Tags: hive, hiveql, beeline

When I connect to a beeline database, I don't need to enter the user and password, I just press enter and I get access to the database.

but when I want to write onto the database I get a permission denied error:

```
Error: java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=hive, access=READ, inode="/apps/hive/warehouse
```

I would know which `default user` should I use to connect to my database in order to add policies to it.

I thought that it's hive, but it seems it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

beeline takes a user account when you connect

```
beeline -u 'url' -n username
```

Use `hdfs dfs -ls` to find tables permissions (assuming you're not using Sentry or Ranger to manage permissions)

In any case, you don't use beeline to add permissions. By default, it's simply HDFS user/group permissions using `chmod` / `chown`, assuming you have ACLs enabled.

Comment: yes I use ranger, but I can't get all permission form hive user in hdfs policies

Comment: The hdfs user is usually a super user

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the below two.

1. Login with **hadoop** user
2. Give full permissions to **/apps/hive/warehouse** folder

Comment: "Give full permissions", How can I give the FULL permissions to all the folder?

Comment: sudo chmod 777 /apps/hive/warehouse

Comment: that gives permissions just for "warehouse" not for all  subfolders

Comment: sudo chmod -R 777 /apps/hive/warehouse

Comment: but the problem is there is some data created by some users should kept confidential

Comment: try this **beeline -u jdbc:hive2://hostname:10000/default -n hadoop org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver -e "show databases;"**

Comment: I think he ignores the `-n hadoop` and he connect with the default user

Comment: I tested the same command with a user who doesn't exist and it's still work